# Combining Get Feature requests within OpenLayers3 Overlay

Tags: javascript, openlayers, overlay

I have a map which currently shows one feature of a layer in an overlay popup when you click on it, as per [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/86qvt32b/1/).

As you can see, it currently displays the address within the overlay. I am looking to show the 'address' and 'name' features within the same overlay, presumably by adding in feature requests.

Also, if possible this will go into a table within the overlay? However I'm not sure where I enter the code for a  to go into the overlay popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var html = feature.get('address');
html += feature.get('name');
html += feature.get('whatever');

content.innerHTML = html;
popup.setPosition(coord);
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want some markup in the popup:

```
var html = '<h3>Here is ' + feature.get('name') + '</h3>';
html += 'And if you need some <button id="" onclick="">click</button>';
```

Got it? It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks @Jonatas, that gives the result below, so it works! But, how would i go about splitting this up into something a bit more user friendly, ideally i'd like to add in a table with buttons in there, i'm unsure where I edit for that to work?  http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/86qvt32b/2/

Comment: You can put whatever you want into this `html` variable. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually just worked this out as per the link below. The only issue I have now is if I have two points in the same location. As you can see with Birmingham, when you click on the point it only brings up the value of the point on top, ideally I would like it to show the values of any points that are in this location? http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/86qvt32b/6/

Comment: Oh, but this is another question. This can be useful to others so create another one.

Comment: Thanks, will do, I've done it in the past but not within an Overlay like this so think it will be different.